# Non-Greedy Regex Fails

Tags: regex

My question has 2 parts...

First, I'm trying to extract the FIRST set of numbers separated by a slash ("12/56" in this case), and ignore the 2nd set (if it exists).

Sample String:

> ```
> some text  12/56    34/67    ABCD1234   --Want to grab "12/56", but ignore "34/67"
> more text  14/58             DEFG5678   --Want to grab "14/58".
> ```

I've tried using `(\d\d\/\d\d)?` as the pattern (non-greedy), however it doesn't stop after the first hit.

Second, once the above problem is solved, I still need to grab the 8-digit code after it (there will ALWAYS be an 8-digit code).  I'd like to use something like `(\d\d\/\d\d)?.+([A-Z0-9]{8})`, however I'd think that the *correct* non-greedy search may stop regex in its tracks.  Is this possible?

Comment: Just to clarify, the string will be "some text 12/56 34/67 ABCD1234 more text 14/58 DEFG5678" and you want to grab 12/56 and 14/58?  
Then further you want the codes ABCD1234 and DEFG5678 ?

Comment: That is correct..however each will be on its own line (unlike how your question was posted).  I want to process each line independently; first match will be the first line, with groups to grab the first value and the second group to grab the 8 digit alphanumeric code.  My problem has been the 'skipping' of an optional secondary ##/## as the sample shows.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `?` after the first capturing group.

```
(\d\d\/\d\d).+([A-Z0-9]{8})
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vdfd), while hovering the mouse over the highlighted match you can see the content of the capturing groups.

**Explanation:**

With the `?` you don't make the group "non-greedy", you make it optional. So, because you lines doesn't start with a digit, the regex skips the optional part and match everything with the following `.+` till your last part.

You don't need a "non-greedy" behaviour here, your pattern will match the first occurrence and you can make a quantifier "ungreedy" but not a group.

Comment: Now I see the light!  Thank you for this solution.  I was getting hung-up when just trying "(\d\d\/\d\d)" and seeing it grab both.  I now see that combining the second grouping with "anything in between" works perfectly well.  Thanks also for the Regexr link...very useful tester!!!

Answer (score 0):

Which language are you using these regular expressions in?  Are you using a "find" or a "match" method?  As long as you're using a "match" method, your last example (the "something like") should almost work as you'd expect - but I'd remove the ? after the first grouping of digits, unless you have a specific need for it:

```
(\d\d/\d\d).+([A-Z0-9]{8})
```

With using the "match" method, this will force both grouping to be populated, in order to complete a successful match.

Comment: If he has multiple of these in one string, he might want a ? after the .+, to stop the pattern from expanding further, unless he has this as default by some modifier

Comment: I will be doing this in VBA, however I've been creating / testing this on www.regexpal.com, which seems to be working quite well...it's my brain that doesn't function properly!

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d\d/\d\d)\s+(?:\d\d/\d\d)?\s*([A-Z0-9]{8})
```

grabs the first but ignores the second set of `nn/nn` strings (if present), then grabs the next 8 uppercase ASCII alnum characters, assuming that nothing but whitespace will be between those items.

The results will then be in groups 1 and 2. So, for example in Python, you'd use

```
reobj = re.compile(r"(\d\d/\d\d)\s+(?:\d\d/\d\d)?\s*([A-Z0-9]{8})")
match = reobj.search(subject)
if match:
    first = match.group(1)
    second = match.group(2)
else:
    print "No match!"
```

Comment: I see...so in this situation, one must put the capturing group in, and ignore the capture (the "?:") and then make that group optional...Excellent, and thanks!